# Why caliburn is not so common like prism? why there are only few who use caliburn?

Tags: wpf, caliburn

I Don't understand this, its a good framework but not many use it.

If you know something I don't please help.

Answer (score 6):

Because Microsoft made Prism and they are a lot of users who do not look beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with bennage!

There are a silent revolution with Caliburn. We started using Caliburn 1,5 year ago, at that time the tutorials were few, and we had some problems finding the information we needed!

Today the amount of information and tutorials on Caliburn is much better than a year ago, but Caliburn is an open-source framework with all its normal pros and cons!

I know customers have shifted from MVVM Light to Caliburn due to limitations and problems with MVVM Light.

In my opinion Caliburn (and Caliburn Micro) is the best choice!

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking into the same, and agree that Caliburn has a whole lot more features than MVVM Light or Prism, especially the auto binding properties/methods/View-VMs that you get in Caliburn, and Prism has too much overhead including configuring the Region Manager, Container, resolving/binding the VMs to the Views etc which we don't really need for our small application.

The main factor as rightly said above is the Prism is officially controlled and backed by Microsoft through its [Microsoft Patterns and Practices Team](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/bb190332).
For the first years, it was exclusively controlled by them , and a new version of PRISM came out almost the same time as a new release of WPF/C#.
It is now , however Open Source, but still a degree of control is maintained.

Caliburn started off as on Open source passion project to show a cleaner implementation of MVVM, and unfortunately, you always run the risk of such a project just losing interest and dying out after a while.
That is a huge turning point.

However, something I can't really find is the differences between Caliburn and Caliburn Micro.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @SurajRao -  I have added to the answer and provided some of the key points. Unfortunately, I came to this page still looking for answers to a related topic myself and I might have got carried away with my own doubts. Your suggestion is Duly Noted.

Comment: I believe it now does answer the question, but also asks a follow-up question. Since the answer can be salvaged, I removed the question. @UdayMehta if you have another question, please don't hasitate and use the Ask Question button for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Change**. *People are afraid of it.*

To add another dimension to this debate, some people that are used to the classical style of MVVM which is implemented in PRISM or MVVM Light are actually intimidated (scared ?) of the Magic Features and new conventions in Caliburn or Caliburn Micro. I know people on my team were very resistant to something that was new and different from what they knew already worked well enough for them.

This is perfectly understandable, I found it a little challenging to grasp it initially myself.

They can, however, take a look at [Caliburn.Light](https://github.com/tibel/Caliburn.Light)

Caliburn.Light is another derivative/subtype of Caliburn. It removes some of the so-called "Magic" features, and instead adds some of the common features from Prism and MVVMLight. Sounds promising, but I haven't tried it myself.

Maybe this just needs better marketing (unlikely, cause free/open source) or at least a dedicated Dev Forum (This is where the MS ecosystem/userbase comes in).
Prism has loads of both. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I haven't come across either for Caliburn.